# Is it possible to report Contacts that have repeat Sales grouped by Sales Associate?

Tags: reporting, custom-object, custom-reports

Objects are Contacts(standard) and Sales Orders(custom).  The Contact object is the Master of the Sales Order object.

So, there can be multiple Sales Orders per Contact.  Under the Sales Order record, there is a field that stores the Employee Name(text field).  It is NOT a lookup field.

I want to create a report that just displays Contacts with repeat sales to a Sales Associate(Employee Name).

So I would want to exclude any Sales Associates from the report that only have 1 sale to a contact.

I am at the point where the report is create and configured/grouped properly, HOWEVER - I am still seeing those Sales Associates that have only 1 sale to a contact.  Is there any way to remove these from showing on the report?

Thanks in advance from everyone reading and assiting in this.

Comment: can you not create a roll up summary on the contact object based on the number of sales orders and filter by the roll up summary field?

Comment: Hi Rao - That doesn't give me to expected result. - This needs to show Contacts that have multiple sales per Sales Associate.  I want to exclude those contacts that only had 1 sale to any associate.

Comment: if you're willing to do apex, you can manage a custom field on sales order called `isOnlySaleByEmployee__c` that is true for first sales by that employee and switches to false when the second sale occurs. Then your report can filter on `isOnlySalesByEmployee = false`

Comment: Hi cropedy - Thanks for the idea, I am going to try that out now.  I'll report back.